# How to generate unique id for each entry in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb

How do I generate a unique ID for each entry into my mongoDB through Postman?

I run postman POST with `http://localhost:8000/api/user/store` and send

```
{
"name":"testname",
"email":"testemail@test.com",
"phone":"testnumber",
"city":"testcity",
}
```

This gets saved in my mongoDB and shows this in my mongoDB compass

```
_id:61f7e48f0c651345677b7775
name:"testname"
email:"testemail@test.com"
phone:"testnumber"
city:"testcity"
__v:0
```

How can I generate a unique ID and add it in between this process such that it gets saved something like this:

```
_id:61f7e48f0c651345677b7775
uniqueID:68465135
name:"testname"
email:"testemail@test.com"
phone:"testnumber"
city:"testcity"
__v:0
```

My model userData.js looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
}, { timeStamps: true })

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
//export model to use in other files
module.exports = User;
```

This is the snippet from `UserController.js` on how the data gets saved

```
// Saves user to the database
const store = (req, res, next) => {
    let user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        city: req.body.city,
    })
    user.save()
        .then(response => {
            res.json({
                message: 'User added successfully!'
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.json({
                message: 'An error occured!'
            })
        })
}
```

The uniqueID can be anything I just added numeric as example. But it has to be unique. How can I do this? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: can you share your model?

Comment: _id is unique isn't it?

Comment: @LucjanGrzesik EDIT-added model

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `_id` from MongoDB as it will always be unique if you don't like the format of the MongoDB `_id` you can change it to  [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid).

---

## Model

**With new `uniqueId` field**

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: string,
  uniqueId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: () => nanoid(7),
    index: { unique: true },
  },
  email: String,
  phone: String,
  city: String,
})
```

---

### You can also just overwrite `_id` with nanoid so it doesn't create an extra field in your schema

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    default: () => nanoid(),
  },
  name: string,
  email: String,
  phone: String,
  city: String,
})
```

---

### Controller

```
// Saves user to the database
const store = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, email, phone, city} = req.body;
  try {
    let user = new User({
      name,
      email,
      phone,
      city,
    });
    const savedUser = await user.save();
    return res.json({
      message: 'User added successfully!',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return res.json({
      message: 'An error occured!',
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: A unique index over the field would be better, since it would both allow querying by the custom ID and protect from duplicates at the DB level.

Comment: Yeah you are right changed my answer

Comment: With the index, there's no need to check if the user exists yet or not. The `save` call would throw an error too, without an extra query.

Comment: This works for the first one only, the next entry still has the previous generated ID itself. Am I doing something wrong? ( the `savedUser` in controller is declared but not used)

Comment: Did you figure it out @Parzival?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, `_id` (`ObjectId`) is already unique, and if you want to provide your own `_id` you just need to set it in the entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate unique id technically but it has to be big enough to not generate the same id, example:

```
function create_UUID(){
    var dt = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = (dt + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
        dt = Math.floor(dt/16);
        return (c=='x' ? r :(r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
}
```

Output:

```
1fe35579-5ce7-46ec-89e0-7e7236700297
```

Source:

https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-math-exercise-23.php

Answer (score 1):

The mongodb javascript driver has `UUID` already:

```
db.foo.insert( {x: new UUID()} );
db.foo.aggregate([ {$project: {x:true, x_type: {$type: "$x"}}} ]);
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61f81af6a565bb368b38e345"),
    "x" : UUID("b639a8b5-2598-429f-92e0-630c6b5bfbdc"),
    "x_type" : "binData"
}
```

If you don't like the actual `UUID` object then capture its string rep.  Note that unfortunately, `toString()` on the object does not yield `892ab869-3339-41b3-a612-5c29871f4e57` but rather the whole of `UUID("892ab869-3339-41b3-a612-5c29871f4e57")` so you have to `substr` it:

```
db.foo.insert( {x: (new UUID()).toString().substr(6,36) });
db.foo.aggregate([ {$project: {x:true, x_type: {$type: "$x"}}} ]);
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61f81b56a565bb368b38e348"),
    "x" : "d5af9fb4-768c-4e17-b69a-8bcd80f8bf1e",
    "x_type" : "string"
}
```

Or, for simplicity you can use the `hex()` method:

```
db.foo.insert( {x: (new UUID()).hex() } );
db.foo.aggregate([ {$project: {x:true, x_type: {$type: "$x"}}} ]);
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61f81ba9a565bb368b38e34e"),
    "x" : "b9810abea4344932b3da15f7f0d58e2c", // note the dashes went away
    "x_type" : "string"
}
```

In all cases, the driver -- **NOT** the server -- will create a unique `_id` if it is not supplied.  Creation of a unique id that is *not* tied to the database (e.g. `_id`) can be valuable when integrating and moving data around (compare with moving `ROWID` out of Oracle in a CSV; not very useful).  NOTE:  The default generated type for `_id` is `ObjectId` which is a type in BSON and is not necessarily tied to MongoDB.  That said, UUID is still more of a "machine/DB key" as compared to a familiar business key which can be made unique.